# Writing in separate columns in csv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
from operator import itemgetter

COLS = 15,21,27
COLS1 = 16,22,28

filename = "result.csv"
getters = itemgetter(*(col-1 for col in COLS))
getters1 =  itemgetter(*(col-1 for col in COLS1))

with open('result.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
        row = zip(getters(row))
    for row1 in csv.reader(csvfile):
        row1 = zip(getters1(row1))
        print(row)
        print(row1)
        
with open('results1.csv', "w", newline='') as f:
    fieldnames = ['AAA','BBB']
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
    for row in row:
        writer.writerow(row)
        writer.writerow(row1)
```

I am getting a NameError: name 'row1' is not defined error. I want to write each of the COLS in a separate column in the results1 file. How would I go about this?

Comment: Can you explain what you intend `for row in row` to mean?

Comment: post the traceback so we have the details of the error.

Comment: I want to read the rows from the result.csv to put it in results1.csv

Comment: Look at `for row1 in csv.reader(csvfile):` - you read the file to completion in the `for` loop just above it, so `csv.reader` won't emit anything and `row1` is never set.

Comment: If the intent is "please tell me how to fix the code": Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and carefully trace what happens when the code runs. We do not provide a debugging service. Before asking, it is necessary to understand **one, specific** problem well enough to a) describe it; b) produce a [mre]. If the intent is "please tell me how to accomplish the task": you will need to **explain what the task is** much more clearly. Show an example of what the input file contains, and **exactly** what the output file should contain as a result.

Answer (score 0):

So, there are few things going on in the code that are potentially leading to errors.

First is the way `csv.reader(csvfile)` works in python. When reading the file with `csv.reader` it basically scans the next line in the file when called and returns it. The csv part in this case simply uses the .cvs format and returns the data in a list, rather than a simple string of text in the standard python file reader. This is fine for a lot of use cases, but the issue here we are running into, is that when you run:

```
for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
    row = zip(getters(row))
```

the csv.reader(csvfile) gets called for every row in the entire file and the for loop only stops when it runs out of data in the "results.csv" file. Meaning, if you want to use the data from each row, you need to store it in some way before running out the file. I think that's what you are trying to achieve with `row = zip(getters(row))` but the issue here is `row` is both being assigned to `zip(getters(row))` and being used as the variable in the for loop. Since you are essentially calling `csv.reader`, returning to variable `row`, then reassigning `row` to being `zip(getters(row))`, you are just writing over the variable `row` every iteration of the for loop and the result is nothing gets stored.

In order to store your csv data, try this:

```
data = [[]]
for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
    temp = zip(getters(row))
    data.append(temp)
```

This will store your row in a list called data.

Then, the second error is the one you are asking about, which is `row1` not being defined. This happened in your code because the for loop ran through every row in the csv file. When you then call `csv.reader` again in the second for loop it can't read anything because the first for loop already read through the entire csv file and it doesn't know to start over at the beginning of the file. Therefore, `row1` never gets declared or assigned, and therefore when you call again it in `writer.writerow(row1)`, `row1` doesn't exist.

There a couple ways to fix this. You could close the file, reopen it again and start from the beginning of the file again. Or you could store it at the same time in the first for loop. So like this:

```
data = [[]]
data1 = [[]]
for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
    temp = zip(getters(row))
    data.append(temp)
    temp2 = zip(getters1(row))
    data2.append(temp2)
```

Now you will have 3 columns of data in both `data` and `data1`.

Now for writing to the `"results1.csv"` file. Here you used row as the for loop variable as well as the iterable to run through, which does not work. Also, you call `writer.writerow(row)` then `writer.writerow(row1)`, which also doesn't work. Try this instead:

```
with open('results1.csv', "w", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
    for row in range(len(data)):
        writer.writerow(data[row] + data1[row])
```

Now it also looks like you want to add headers for each column in `fieldnames = ['AAA','BBB']` . Unfortunetly, `csv.writer` does not have an easy way to do this, instead `csv.DictWriter` and `writer.writeheader()` must be used first.

```
with open('results1.csv', "w", newline='') as f:
    fieldnames = ['A','A','A','B','B','B']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f,delimiter=",", fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
    for row in range(len(data)):
        writer.writerow(data[row] + data1[row])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer], and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. That means, among other things, that we want questions to be clear, specific and **focused** - such that they can be part of a **searchable** library. If someone is just posting code that has multiple problems and making a vague request like "How would I go about this?", then that is not a useful question, and it *should not be answered*. Answers to unsuitable questions make it harder to clean up the site.

Comment: (As for writing style, we want answers to be direct and to the point, without "talking to" the OP. Write like you'd want it to appear if you were reading it in a "how to solve practical problems" book - not like you were listening to it from a friend or mentor.)